# How should the UI of controls be designed when developing software?

Tags: qt

I have been developing software using Qt recently, and there are many commonly used controls such as buttons and dropdown menus. Now I want to make the styles of these controls more aesthetically pleasing. What books or materials should I read? I want to learn it myself.

I searched for relevant blog posts online, but couldn't find a suitable answer

Comment: Have you read about [style sheets](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet.html)?

Comment: Seeking book recommendations is [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.